# Use AWS SDK using IAM Role - Without Root Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to use AWS SDK to upload files to S3 bucket without using root credentials. I have an IAM role, but NO root credentials. Is there any API that is available to do the same?

As of now, I am using the following dode.

```
protected  void transferToS3(String s3BucketName, String folderPath,String 
s3FolderName) {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("aceessKey", 
    "secretkey");
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);

        AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        TransferManager xfer_mgr = new TransferManager(s3Client);
        AmazonS3Client ac;
            try {
                MultipleFileUpload xfer = xfer_mgr.uploadDirectory(s3BucketName,
                        s3FolderName, new File(folderPath), true);
                xfer.waitForCompletion();
            } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you're running this code on EC2 or in Lambda then launch the compute with an appropriately-permissioned IAM role and let the AWS SDK automatically retrieve credentials for you.

Comment: When you say you have an "IAM role" what exactly do you mean? Do you have credentials that will let you assume the role, or are you running on an instance which has that role (instance profile) assigned to it.

Comment: I have credentials (email/password) to assume the IAM role on AWS.

Comment: Credentials that use an email as the User ID are **root credentials** and should generally be avoided for security reasons. You should instead be using an **IAM User** when calling AWS services. The IAM User can then assume an IAM Role if desired.

Comment: Ok, I am looking for an API call to pass the IAM User role, and upload the given folder/files to S3 bucket.